# Unable to install metasploit-framework

Tags: apt, package-management

```
└─# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && \
  chmod 755 msfinstall && \
  ./msfinstall
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6034  100  6034    0     0  16999      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16997
Adding metasploit-framework to your repository list..Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
Updating package cache..OK
Checking for and installing update..
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  metasploit-framework
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/321 MB of archives.
After this operation, 793 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 453066 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../metasploit-framework_6.3.30+20230813102701~1rapid7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking metasploit-framework (6.3.30+20230813102701~1rapid7-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/metasploit-framework_6.3.30+20230813102701~1rapid7-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/metasploit-payloads-2.0.148/data/meterpreter/ext_server_python.x86.debug.dll.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/metasploit-framework_6.3.30+20230813102701~1rapid7-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```